# EF database table created with extra fields not found in the associated model definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create an MVC project in VS2013 and have created some models that seem to be generating tables with additional columns. For instance I have the following model:

```
namespace JCF_MVC.Models
{
    public class Actor
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid home phone number entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Home Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }

        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid mobile/cellular phone number entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile/Cellular Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid work phone number entered.")]
        [Display(Name = "Work Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A person is required.")]
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The CreateTable statement generated for that Model is the following:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Actors",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    HomePhone = c.String(),
                    MobilePhone = c.String(),
                    WorkPhone = c.String(),
                    Address_ID = c.Int(),
                    Person_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Incident_ID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.Address_ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.Person_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Incidents", t => t.Incident_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Address_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Person_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Incident_ID);
```

You will notice that there is no **Incident or Incident_ID** in my Model so it is unclear to me why the column, foreign key and index for this is being added.

Comment: How does your incident model look like? Does it contain any reference to the Actor model?

Comment: yes it does it looks something like this: public class Incident
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
...
        [Display(Name = "Suspects")]
        public virtual List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
...
    }

Comment: Then that's why it contains an foreign key. For Entity Framework to map a list of actors to an incident, the actor class needs to contain a foreign key to incident. Now this is not visible in your model. But underwater, Entity Framework generates this key for you.

Comment: So this is expected then... Thx, @Rikkos. One more question then, when you say "not visible" does that mean that I do not need to add a Incident_ID field when I create a new Actor as part of the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() processing?

Comment: Out the top of my head: that is correct. If you add your actor to your incident and mark the entity as updated or added, Entity Framework will take care of the foreign keys for you. Something worth knowing: if you create a property called IncidentId and virtual property Incident in your actor class, Entity Framework detects this relation through convention.